# How do I query through 2 collections in Firebase using onSnapshot and setOrders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working with Firebase, specifically Firestore for the first time and I have ran into a error blocking my progress. I have a document with 2 nested collections and I am trying to query through them and order them in descending order. Then using Firestore Snapshot feature I am trying to map the doc and capture any changes. I know Firebase's syntax has changed and when I run the code on my localhost I am getting this error:

> Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users/JAVTmLaWdWOTpXH5iPw25E2CF7z2/orders has 3.

I have tried different things while debugging like creating 2 different documents for "users" and "orders" but have had no success. Below I will attach the code that has been giving me these errors and I was wondering if anyone would know how to correctly use the new Firestore syntax. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Orders.css";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import { db } from "./firebase";
import { doc, onSnapshot, orderBy, query, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import Order from "./Order";

function Orders() {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      const orderRef = doc(db, "users", user?.uid, "orders");
      const q = query(orderRef, orderBy("created", "desc"));
      onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        setOrders(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            data: doc.data(),
          }))
        );
      });
    } else {
      setOrders([]);
    }
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div className="orders">
      <h1>Your Orders</h1>

      <div className="orders__order">
        {orders?.map((order) => (
          <Order order={order} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Orders;
```

I tried creating one document for "users" and then adding to that document to include the collection within that document called "orders".

The expected result is that I receive no errors and can the orders correctly in descending order.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code comes from this line:

```
const orderRef = doc(db, "users", user?.uid, "orders");
```

The path in this line (`users/JAVTmLaWdWOTpXH5iPw25E2CF7z2/orders`) points to a collection, not to a specific document in that collection. So to create a reference to that **collection**, you'll want to use:

```
const orderRef = collection(db, "users", user?.uid, "orders");
```

---

> I have a document with 2 nested collections and I am trying to query through them...

Firestore can only query a single collection at a time, or across all collections with one specific name. There is no support to query across multiple collections with different names at this time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Spent hours trying to debug this and that finally worked. Also thank you for the explanation Frank